# HP Coolsense for Ubuntu?

Tags: hp, temperature

I have an HP Pavilion M6-1045dx running Ubuntu 12.10, but after ten minutes it feels hot. Is there any HP cool-sense for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

You should consider installing jupiter

You can select power modes with it, which control the way power is used, it really keeps the temperature down. It also really saves out battery.

> open terminal and do this.
>
> add the repository
>
> `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/jupiter`
>
> update
>
> `sudo apt-get update`
>
> install jupiter
>
> `sudo apt-get install jupiter`
>
> and to other people reading this and are using an Asus EEPC netbook,
>   install this asswell
>
> `sudo apt-get install jupiter-support-eee`

Have a nice day :)

Comment: jupiter discontinued !

Comment: Good luck I posted this 4 years ago. Do you have a recommendation to use now? Since I haven't used Jupiter in a long time(actually forgot about it).