# Whether HP Pavilion G6-2007TX supports Ubuntu?

Tags: hp-pavilion

Sir,

I am having HP Pavilion G6-2007TX lapto. The laptop is provided with Windows 8. I need to replace the OS with Ubuntu 12.10. I need to know, whether my laptop will support Ubuntu or not.

I am also having some 10-20 GB of important data, and i dont want it to be lost.

Requirement / Expectations:

1. Drivers for AMD Drivers, Dolby Sound Available.
2. Bluetooth Drivers, Wifi Drivers, LAN Drivers, Touchpad drivers and Webcam drivers to be available.
3. it should be able to manage heating i.e. temperature regulations. HP provides Cool Sense Technology for Windows. I suppose Ubuntu might have some app/ppas for such things.

Here are the complete [specifications/configurations](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=us&lc=en&dlc=en&docname=c03247857):

Answer (score 0):

We really can't answer the question whether a particular hardware will work with ubuntu.

[List of ubuntu certified HP laptops](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/desktop/make/HP/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=IafephDYmaq731dg4LRiFO22PUYO4cB8&query=&category=Laptop&category=Netbook&release=12.04%20LTS&level=Any)

The only think to know is perform testing.

- Create a live USB media or DVD media using 64bit ubuntu. Plugin the live cd/usb and run from it.
- Running from live USB/CD will not make any changes to your system but you can test all the functionalists.
- **Regarding drivers:** Ubuntu contain generic drivers and most of the (or all of the) devices will work out of the box.

  But due to license issue, ubuntu installation cannot include 3rd party proprietary drivers. Such as graphics driver from intel, broadcom wireless driver.

  If you search this site, you will get detailed instruction on how to install.

  Like - [What is the correct way to install proprietary ATI Catalyst Video Drivers (fglrx) directly from AMD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx) or [How do I get AMD/Intel Hybrid Graphics drivers to work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205112/how-do-i-get-amd-intel-hybrid-graphics-drivers-to-work) or [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

  In general you can look at this question : [How do I install additional drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-extra-drivers)
- **You are replacing an OS. If you are not good with partition type (Legacy/ UEFI) and their operations. Be safe, copy your data to some external drive.**
- Have a look here also - [Ubuntu 12.10 64bit installation on HP Pavilion g6](https://askubuntu.com/questions/275786/ubuntu-12-10-64bit-installation-on-hp-pavilion-g6?rq=1) & [HP Coolsense for Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/256592/hp-coolsense-for-ubuntu)

After installation, if you face any problem you are welcome here to ask your problem.